# ¿Como hacer que un div ocupe todo el alto de un div contenedor?

Tags: html, css, div, height

Problema:

El div llamado "boxNavRight" no ocupa el alto total, me gustaría que ocupe todo el espacio del div "boxNav".

no he logrado conseguir esto, cuando asigno una altura definida a "boxNav" ejemplo 500px funciona pero no debe tener una altura definida, ya que cuando la pantalla es pequeña al tener la propiedad flex-wrap envía al div "boxNavRight" hacia abajo y si tiene una altura definida el contener padre este se desborda..

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-size: var(--text-small);
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--color-second);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--color-second);
  padding: var(--margin-medium);
}
.boxNav {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: var(--margin-medium);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-medium);
  font-size: var(--text-small);
}
.boxNavLeft {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.boxlistUl {
  margin-left: var(--margin-medium);
}
.boxNavRight {
  width: 450px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="boxNav">
      <div class="boxNavLeft">
          <div class="boxList">
              <ul class="boxlistUl">
                  <li>a</li>
                  <li>b</li>
                  <li>c</li>
                  <li>d</li>
                  <li>e</li>
                  <li>f</li>
                  <li>g</li>
                  <li>h</li>
                  <li>i</li>
                  <li>j</li>
                  <li>k</li>
                  <li>l</li>
                  <li>m</li>
                  <li>n</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="boxNavRight">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur deleniti nam libero
              magni amet esse praesentium officiis excepturi quis repellat? Blanditiis quas incidunt
              adipisci quo quia qui quos? Id, laborum!
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías darle una altura fija al contenedor `boxNavRight`, y que esa altura sea el mismo que del contenedor `boxNav`:

```
.boxNavRight {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

Por cierto, no hace falta que el contenedor `boxNavRight` sea flexible, no ocurre ningún efecto en especial, aquí lo quité.

---

También apliqué un `@media` para que la altura vuelva a como estaba, este cambio ocurrirá cuando el ancho de la pantalla sea de `965px`, y adicionalmente, el ancho ocupará todo el contenedor del `boxNav` con `width: 100%`:

```
@media (max-width: 965px) {
  .boxNavRight {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

---

[**Código completo**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/OJwYQRB).

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple es ocupar css Grid, el truco está en esta instrucción

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px,1fr));
```

Que dices que va a haber un número indeterminado de columnas (el repeat hace esto), pero en tu caso solo tienes 2 elementos, por lo que la única posibilidad son una o 2 columnas, es decir tirar lo de la derecha para abajo

Luego `minmax` disce que las columnas serán de 500px de lo contrarios ocuparan todo el ancho

```css
.boxNav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px,1fr));
}
.boxNavRight {
  width: 450px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="boxNav">

   <ul class="boxlistUl">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>j</li>
    <li>k</li>
    <li>l</li>
    <li>m</li>
    <li>n</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="boxNavRight">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur deleniti nam libero
              magni amet esse praesentium officiis excepturi quis repellat? Blanditiis quas incidunt
              adipisci quo quia qui quos? Id, laborum!
          </p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```